# Showing $\{(x, y) : x^{2} > y\}$ is an open set

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

how can I show $\{(x, y) : x^{2} > y\}$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$? I have not seen a proof of this kind, so I was wondering if someone can help me with this problem as an example. The book I'm reading doesn't help much.

I thought that maybe I can just say that $\partial S  = \{(x, y) : x^{2} = y\}$ is the boundary and $\partial S \cap S = \emptyset$. But then I thought that maybe it isn't enough to state the boundary, and I need to  prove that the set you are claiming is the boundary.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The map$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb{R}^2&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&(x,y)&\mapsto&x^2-y\end{array}$$is continuous, the set $(0,\infty)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$ and your set is $f^{-1}\bigl((0,\infty)\bigr)$

Comment: I am not familiar with using functions to show openness yet. Can you help me in another way ?

Comment: For each $(x,y)$ in your set, you can compute the distance $\delta$ from $(x,y)$ to tha parabola $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\,y=x^2\}$. Then $\delta>0$ and the open disk centered at $(x,y)$ with radius $\delta$ will be a subset of your set.

Comment: It can be shown that a function f is continuous iff the preimage of any open set is open. (It seems like op is not aware of this). Hence since $ (0,\infty)$ is an open set, then its preimage is also open, and its preimage happens to be the set you are trying to prove is open.

Comment: @Alexandros You made me feel silly. I should have explained this to the OP!